# Could Not start Rails Server - 'rails s' creates a new rails app inside existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server

I have cloned a Rails Project into my local. I did a rake db:migrate. I worked fine. Now I want to start my server. I run the command

```
rails s
```

**This command actually creates a new project inside the existing app.** 
Why is this happening?

It throws the following trace and server did not start.

```
 /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.16/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
  exists  
  exists  app/controllers
  exists  app/helpers
  exists  app/models
  exists  app/views/layouts
  exists  config/environments
  exists  config/initializers
  exists  config/locales
  exists  db
  exists  doc
  exists  lib
  exists  lib/tasks
  exists  log  
  exists  test/fixtures    
  exists  tmp/sockets
  exists  tmp/cache
  exists  tmp/pids
   identical  Rakefile
   identical  README
   identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb     b
overwrite config/initializers/session_store.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y
   force  config/initializers/session_store.rb
overwrite config/initializers/cookie_verification_secret.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y  
  identical  script/about
  identical  script/console
  identical  script/dbconsole
  identical  script/destroy
  identical  script/generate   
  identical  public/404.html
  identical  public/422.html
  identical  public/500.html
  identical  public/index.html
  identical  public/favicon.ico
  identical  public/robots.txt
  identical  public/images/rails.png
  identical  public/javascripts/prototype.js
  identical  public/javascripts/effects.js
 identical  public/javascripts/dragdrop.js
```

Should I change any configuration?

Comment: I am in my application folder only. Lenovo-G570:~/academics$  rails s. this is what i ran. academics is my application's name.

Comment: Interesting, this output is from running `rails generate`... have you also tried running the full command (`rails server`)?

Comment: Yup. This app seems to have another Rails app inside this. Is that the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be on older version of rails, Rails version < 3.0.

In Rails version < 3.0 you have to start server with

```
ruby script/server
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Clone project.
2. Got to inside project directory using console window.
3. setup database inside config/database.yml
4. run: bundle install
5. run: rake db:create
6. run: rake db:migrate
7. run rails s
8. visit: http://localhost:3000
9. Enjoy